# Using IF & AND statements with Checkboxes on a Userform

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, macros, userform

A little background: I have so far created a userform with checkboxes that each run separate macros initially then when unchecked they run an identical macro to return to the "normal" state. This was done using an IF, Else statement.

My question is how to combine the If statement with an AND statement so when/if two boxes are checked they run a different code or macro.

I am still very new to VBA and coding but it seems like a rather simple idea to me as I got the IF else statement to work. But for some reason the code I have been trying hasn't been working and I dont recieve any errors it just doesn't do anything when I have both boxes checked.

The code I have been trying is:

```
Private Sub cbXray_Click()

If cbXray.Value = True And cbSCH40.Value = True Then
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=((RC[-6]*'Sched 40 Table Data'!R[1]C[1])+(RC[-5]*'Sched 40 Table Data'!R[1]C[-10])+(RC[-4]*'Sched 40 Table Data'!R[1]C[-9])+(RC[-3]*'Sched 40 Table Data'!R[1]C[-8])+(RC[-2]*'Sched 40 Table Data'!R[1]C[-7])+(RC[-1]*'Sched 40 Table Data'!R[1]C[-6]))"
Range("P7").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P7:P30"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("P7:P30").Select

Else

Range("P7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=((RC[-6]*'Sched 40 Table Data'!R[1]C[-11])+(RC[-5]*'Sched 40 Table Data'!R[1]C[-10])+(RC[-4]*'Sched 40 Table Data'!R[1]C[-9])+(RC[-3]*'Sched 40 Table Data'!R[1]C[-8])+(RC[-2]*'Sched 40 Table Data'!R[1]C[-7])+(RC[-1]*'Sched 40 Table Data'!R[1]C[-6]))"
Range("P7").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P7:P30"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("P7:P30").Select
End If


End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting your code as follows:

```
Private Sub cbSCH40_Click()
    cbs_Check 
End Sub

Private Sub cbXray_Click()
    cbs_Check
End Sub

Private Sub cbs_Check()
    With Me
        If .cbXray And .cbSCH40 Then
            'code to run when both checkboxes are checked
        ElseIf .cbXray Then
            'code to run when only cbXray is checked
        ElseIf .cbSCH40 Then
            'code to run when only cbSCH40 is checked
        Else
            'code to run when neither cbXray nor cbSCH40 is checked
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, the values changed when both are checked however only xray checkbox switches values when its checked by itself. the cbSCH40 checkbox now wont change values when it is checked by itself

Comment: nevermind I added the code wrong and put an extra line in. THANK YOU SO MUCH it worked.

Comment: you wouldnt happen to know how to apply it to 3 or 4 checkboxes checked  at the same time would you?